# Facebook PHP SDK Upload Photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Trying to upload a photo rendered on my server to the facebook album of the user on the fly. Since FB Docs are very,very,very bad (to say the least) I was hoping for someone to show me some good code examples of Graph API calls with the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this.

```
     try {
        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport('http://www.example.com/');
        $response = $facebook->api(
          '/me/photos/',
          'post',
          array(
            'message' => 'This is my image caption',
            'source' => '@/path/to/image' // @-sign must be the first character
          )
        );
      }
      catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log('Could not post image to Facebook.');
      }
```

EDIT: First you need to authenticate, by using this code.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  'cookie' => TRUE,
  'domain' => $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
));

$facebook->getSession();

try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $me = NULL;
}

if ( is_null($me) ) {
  $auth_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'req_perms' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos'
  ));

  header("Location: $auth_url");
}
```

[Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) is a link to all permissions you can ask the user for.

Comment: What does post goal to wall mean? and what should www.example.com be?

Comment: Sorry. I swiped from one of my own projects and missed to change that text. It means that the Facebook API threw an exception and I log it to the PHP error_log in order to check it at a later time. example.com would be the domain name of the site that is running the script.

Comment: And you'd say this is the way to go at Graph API Requests? Just change the parameters and the url (/me/photos) to whatever I need?

Comment: Yes. It's as simple as that. Once you have initialized the API with your application's parameters. However you have to make sure to ask the user for permissions to do what you want to do. I'll add an example of that in my answer.

Comment: remove the trailing slash after `photos` and instead of `me` use the album ID to add to a specific album.

Comment: @ifaour: It will work as it is (with trailing slash). But yes, you can exchange "me" for a an album ID, friend ID or whatever depending on the action you are performing.

Comment: @9muses: change `$this->facebook->api` to `$facebook->api`

Comment: @ifaour Thanks, I did that now :)