# Confirming a Facebook Access Token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, devise

We're using the Facebook JS SDK to authenticate users to our application, then sending that information to the server back end to log our user into the application (we support multiple forms of authentication but we can only support FB using a client side flow).

FB is able to log in correctly, I'm able to authenticate the user and everything else, but there's one wrinkle that I'm not sure how to handle, and I'm having difficulty finding anything in the documentation about it. Facebook sends back an `accessToken` in addition to an `id`. My question is, how do I verify on the server side that the `accessToken` is correct for the given `id`? I want to make sure that the data the user sends us matches what Facebook sent them, and I can't imagine this is that out of the ordinary, yet I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response from Facebook should be a [signed_request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) string that can authenticate that the data is genuine with and decoded to yield the user id and an oauth token for the user.

Passing this along with the other response to your server-side code should allow you to validate everything pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this answer from another question! It uses try-catch. It is probably the only way to verify that the authentication and the permissions are valid! That's how they do in their examples

[Facebook OAuthException: (#1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124996/facebook-oauthexception-1/11834038#11834038)

I dont think facebook provides any other way of checking

Comment: I struggle to believe that's the only way to confirm server-side that the user's submitted data is valid. How does FB expect developers to deal with the possibility of credential forgery?

Comment: well, to be serious, when I saw the way the sdk was made... I was pretty shocked I must say... I had to work with a lot of OAuth type api and facebook one's is not that user friendly.My partner worked with facebook api and he was also pretty much disappointed!